# Class 'TaskPayload' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'EventPayload'

Tags: kotlinx.serialization

I have a simple sealed class and a concrete class using `@Serializable`. However when compiling I always end up with an error.

```kotlin
// EventPayload.kt
@Serializable
sealed class EventPayload {
    val type: String
        get() = this::class.simpleName!!
}
```

```kotlin
// TaskPayload.kt
@Serializable
data class TaskPayload(
    val initiator: String
) : EventPayload()
```

The error

```
Class 'TaskPayload' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'EventPayload'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'TaskPayload' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'EventPayload'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.
```

Comment: Could you please use a question title which is not specific to your code? At a glance, [this should work](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#sealed-classes) (though I'm not certain you included the code that's triggering this compilation warning; the place where serialization happens). What have you tried/does work? What version of `kotlinx.serialization` are you using? Have you browsed the Github repo for bug reports?

Comment: I just had the same thing happen, but at runtime. Not compile time. I did a clean build both on the command line (gradle for me) and in the ide (intellij) and everything cleared up. Probably only needed to run gradle clean, but I hit it with everything I had.

Comment: @MikeTwo's solution of simply running gradle clean did the trick for me. Can't believe I've been pulling my hair out for an hour over this. Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone (including my future self) stumbles upon this again, I have found another possible cause. I moved my class to another file, and so the qualified name of the class (and thus the type key) subtly changed. Adding the `SerialName` annotation with the old qualified name solved my issue.